# Find row containing string, then return that row and all following rows of text file with awk

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, command-line, scripting

Apologies for any duplication, but most questions I've come across relate to getting a specific value from a field in a row, or using `tail` to get `n` tailing lines from a file, where `n` is known *a priori*. I'm looking to find a row where a value is matched, and then get all fields in that row AND all following rows. Details below.

I have data files returned from an online database that have a variable number of metadata header rows containing information about the query criteria used to search the database. After these header rows is a tidy dataframe. Example:

```
Query date: February 3, 2020, 1:34:57 PM
Database: <database name>
\n
Search criteria:
\n
Geographic bounding box coordinates: -130.00 20.00; -130.00 24.00; -120.00 24.00; -120.00 20.00
Sample type: rocks > sediments > dust
\n
SAMPLE ID,REFERENCE,LONGITUDE,LATITUDE,X,Y,Z,A
56,Author (YYYY) Title: Journal,-127.3,22,1.7,2.3,0,0.55
56,Author (YYYY) Title: Journal,-127.34,22.4,1.9,1.3,0.5
```

I have successfully found the row containing data field names using:

```
SID=$(awk -F, '{ if ($1 == "SAMPLE ID") print NR }' data.csv)
```

`echo $SID` returns `9`, as expected

Now I want to take that row of field names and all of the following rows that contain the data and send them to a new file. In other words, I wish to parse the whole input file, and send the rows where `NR >= $SID` to a new file.

This is the code I've been using, but it instead just returns almost all of the data, except for a few rows. I can't figure out how to get the data I want, or why it's omitting the rows that it is.

`awk -F, -v r=$SID '{ if (NR >= $r) print $0}' data.csv > output.csv`

Here's my expected output:

```
SAMPLE ID,REFERENCE,LONGITUDE,LATITUDE,X,Y,Z,A
56,Author (YYYY) Title: Journal,-127.3,22,1.7,2.3,0,0.55
56,Author (YYYY) Title: Journal,-127.34,22.4,1.9,1.3,0.5
```

Any help would be great! If it wasn't clear, I'm totally new to awk! Meaning I'd also welcome links to any good introductory materials for learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In awk, `$r` would refer to the value of the `r`<sup>th</sup> *field*, rather than the value of `r` itself. Your solution should work if you just replace `$r` by `r` :

```
awk -F, -v r=$SID '{ if (NR >= r) print $0}' data.csv
```

or (more idiomatically, using the *default print action*)

```
awk -F, -v r=$SID 'NR >= r' data.csv
```

---

However there's really no need to do it in two steps - either

```
awk -F, '$1 == "SAMPLE ID" {p=1} p' data.csv
```

or even (ignoring the CSV structure altogether)

```
awk '/^SAMPLE ID,/{p=1} p' data.csv
```

should work as well.

Comment: Interestingly, your first 2 suggestions continued to return the full contents of the file, but the 3rd suggestion:
`awk -F, '$1 == "SAMPLE ID" {p=1} p' data.csv > output.csv`
did the trick! Can I ask what `{p=1} p` does?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: For the intellectually curious, I did find another solution:

1) save `sid` variable as in the question

2) `nrecords=`awk -F, 'END {print NR}' data.csv`

3) `let "nout = $nrecords - $sid + 1"`

4) `tail -n $nout data.csv > output.csv`

Comment: @jaymullr the first 2 suggestions assume that you have assigned the appropriate value to shell variable `SID` (using your `SID=$(awk -F, '{ if ($1 == "SAMPLE ID") print NR }' data.csv)` command for example). Did you do so? Otherwise (if `$SID` evaluates to zero) then all lines will be printed.

Comment: I thought I had defined `SID` as stated in the question, but I wonder if there was a typo somewhere, because I quit my shell, started fresh, and now your first solution works correctly.

Who knew that it was the `$r` that was getting me, though: I didn't realize variables declared didn't need the leading `$`

Comment: @jaymullr yes in awk, `$r` would refer to the value of the `r`th *field*, rather than the value of `r` itself

Comment: doh! of course. thanks for your patience; i've marked your answer accepted.

Comment: @jaymullr thanks! happy to help

Comment: You can also use awk's **'range' format**: `awk -F, '$1=="SAMPLE ID",0' data.csv` or sed's equivalent: `sed -n '/^SAMPLE ID,/,$p' data.csv`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes that's even better! TBH I'd never thought about using `0` (false) as the end of a `PAT1,PAT2` range